# Online Compiler won't run more than one class

Tags: java

I am using the online compiler "onlinegdp" to run java and I am unable to use multiple files in my programming. The exact same code works on eclipse so I am unsure where the problem is.

I don't know enough about java to try anything other that Object myObject = newObject(); . So anything would be helpful.

This is what is in my worker class

```
public class Worker
{
  private int hours;
  private double rate;
public Worker ()
{
  hours = 999;
  rate = 999;
}
public Worker (int nHours, double nRate)
{
  hours = nHours;
  rate = nRate;
}
public int getHours ()
{
  return hours;
}
public void setHours (int nHours)
{
  hours = nHours;
}
public double getRate ()
{
  return rate;
}
public void setRate (double nRate)
{
  rate = nRate;
}
public double paycheck ()
{
  return rate * hours;
}
public void raiseRate (double raiseRate)
{
  rate = raiseRate + rate;
}

}
```

This is the main class

```
public class Main
{

public static void main (String[]args)
{
  Worker bob = new Worker ();
  System.out.println (bob.getHours ());
  System.out.println (bob.getRate ());
  bob.setHours (9);
  bob.setRate (7.9);
  System.out.println (bob.getHours ());
  System.out.println (bob.getRate ());
  System.out.println (bob.payCheck ());
  System.out.println (bob.raiseRate ());
}
}
```

I got this error 
Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol

    Worker bob = new Worker ();

    ^

  symbol:   class Worker

  location: class Main

Comment: What is the exact compiler error? Can you compile your code on the command line without Eclipse? Where is this "onlinegdp" compiler? What is Worker? Why should it return 999? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: do you have Worker object in online IDE?

Comment: OnlineGDB handles multiple files just fine.  Did you make sure to create a new file on there that contains the definition of your `Worker` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how onlinegdp - online compiler will save another class file & reference it. If they have functionality then you can try to add them in package & import that file using package.

> It's pain to see the folder/project structure on most of the online compiler. They are meant to run small snippet & not to run the whole project.

Below is the snippet you can run on `onlinegdp` without creating the different file.

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Worker bob = new Worker ();
      System.out.println (bob.getHours ());
  }

  static public class Worker
  {
    private int hours;
    private double rate;
    public Worker ()
    {
      hours = 999;
      rate = 999;
    }
    public Worker (int nHours, double nRate)
    {
      hours = nHours;
      rate = nRate;
    }
    public int getHours ()
    {
      return hours;
    }
    public void setHours (int nHours)
    {
      hours = nHours;
    }
    public double getRate ()
    {
      return rate;
    }
    public void setRate (double nRate)
    {
      rate = nRate;
    }
    public double paycheck ()
    {
      return rate * hours;
    }
    public void raise (double raise)
    {
      rate = raise + rate;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was very helpful. I'll continue to right my code on OnlineGDP in one file now.

Answer (score -1):

just rename the file with .java
[screenshot of new file added as tab with .java extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrfz9.png)

Comment: In the question I can see `Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol` which means OP is working with a .java file.